# Multiplying the number by the value pass in select option when click + in input type number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to multiply value pass from input tag type number by value pass from select tag.

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" value="0" id="input" name="word_count" value="500" style="text-align: center;" />
  <select id="work" onchange="myFunction();" name="work">
    <option>-Select-</option>
    <option value="article">Article</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("work").value;
  if (document.getElementById("work").value == "article") {
    var w = 5;
    if (document.getElementById("input")) {
      var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
      var wc = w * x;
      document.getElementById("total_amount").value = +wc;
      document.getElementById("np").value = +wc;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Do you mean multiplying the input value with the select tag's selected index? I don't see an integer value in the select. How to multiply?

Comment: @ivan86 yes when one click add (input type="number") the number pass from is multiply by the value pass from select tag. forgive me with poor English

Comment: @dominictonui but a string can't be multiplied as the values in the `option` tags are strings (like `value="article"`).

Comment: @ths I have converted  the string from select tag already(var x = document.getElementById("work").value;
  if (document.getElementById("work").value == "article") {
  var w = 5;)

Comment: post your `JavaScript` also as that would help us.

Comment: @ths <script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction() { 
  var x = document.getElementById("work").value;
  if (document.getElementById("work").value == "article") {
  var w = 5;
  if (document.getElementById("input")) {
   var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var wc = w * x;
  document.getElementById("total_amount").value =  +wc;
  document.getElementById("np").value =  +wc;
}
}

Comment: @dominictonui It'll be way more readable if you edit your question and place the `JavaScript` part.

Comment: @ths check I have edit the post

Comment: @dominictonui the code you provided just works as expected ! What do you want to get as an output ?

Comment: @ths when I input a number let say 200 and select option article, its works fine but when I add another option lets say proof reading and select, it does not automatically refresh the results. Forgive me i have terrible English

Comment: that's because you didn't tell `JavaScript` by what number the `input`'s value is going to be multiplied when another `option` is selected as only the number `5` is used only and only if the selected `option`'s value is `article`.

Comment: @ths I have, my issue is, let say I have given proof reading a value of 20. When this(proof reading) is selected it does not refresh automatically until i refresh the site and select proof reading option in order to reflect the results i want.

Comment: @dominictonui no it works ! Try to paste your full code so i'll post an answer for you.

Answer (score -1):

1. You didn't have tags with **id** **total_amount** and **np**. I added them to the HTML. (I added `<span></span>` tags, so I changed the **value** to **textContent** at the end of the conditional)
2. You redeclared `var x` (and redefined it) in your conditional - I renamed it to **z** (it might not have caused a problem, but just to be sure). Actually if you'd done it with the **let** keyword, it would've thrown an exception).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("work").value;
  console.log(x)

  if (document.getElementById("work").value == "article") {
    var w = 5;
    if (document.getElementById("input")) {
      // renamed x to z
      var z = document.getElementById("input").value;
      var wc = w * z;

      // not .value but .textContent
      document.getElementById("total_amount").textContent = +wc;
      document.getElementById("np").textContent = +wc;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" value="0" id="input" name="word_count" value="500" style="text-align: center;" />
  <select id="work" onchange="myFunction();" name="work">
    <option disabled selected>-Select-</option>
    <option value="article">Article</option>
  </select>
</div>
Total amount: <span id="total_amount"></span><br /> NP: <span id="np"></span>
```

Comment: Then it seems the only problem was that you didn't have the elements in your HTML that you tried to get (and set their values)

Comment: *// not .value but .textContent...* Who did tell that the element with the `ID = np` is not an `input` to use `textContent` instead of `value` when from the OP's code  you can tell that that element `#np` is an `input` as he (the OP) used the `value` attribute.

Comment: @muka.gergely and if I want to change the input value and affect #np and #total_amount automatically without refreshing?